Windows Explorer is in an infinite crash loop after installing a MS Store App
I'm running Windows 11 23H2.
I installed this AutoHotKey port from the MS store:
https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nq8q8j78637?hl=en-gb&gl=US/
Immediately after installing, my windows explorer kept crashing and trying to run again in an infinite loop.
Things I tried to fix it:

Uninstalling app from powershell command line (Remove-AppxPackage)
Rebooting.
Rebooting in safe mode.
sfc /scannow and DISM commands

I have been unable to find a solution to this problem.
Please don't download this app in your main windows. Either install it on a VM or create a system restore point before installing (not sure if that will help though)
Here is the Windows Error Report from the Event Viewer:
Fault bucket 1751948585466082502, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: explorer.exe
P2: 10.0.22621.3733
P3: c47c2769
P4: Taskbar.dll
P5: 10.0.22621.3733
P6: 1ab0942e
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000002ee62
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.4b438724-4ace-48a5-a5c0-826d365205f3.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.5e00b52f-1c52-4024-9e2e-d64e9b02f238.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_4a9574a8c4e5da34b0324decbbb5b1c64c5e9_7c1e4220_cab_f58bd7c0-be73-4a72-a72a-b86bc956f056\WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_OneTrace_User_Logger_20240622_1_EC_0_inject.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.9ce3022e-f890-46fb-8a3a-bad0ca28b543.tmp.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_4a9574a8c4e5da34b0324decbbb5b1c64c5e9_7c1e4220_cab_f58bd7c0-be73-4a72-a72a-b86bc956f056\WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector_inject.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.0506c89e-03e9-4511-85f4-e0d527853a5a.tmp.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.4c40e27b-3fef-4c39-b955-04164263c799.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.768becf5-0144-4f51-8355-da456218c52a.tmp.txt
\\?\C:\Users\agarw\AppData\Local\Temp\WER.4eabef8e-a930-46f6-9337-daa9f56a8002.tmp.appcompat.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.6c0752da-eb5f-42bf-ab91-543c2f809f01.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_4a9574a8c4e5da34b0324decbbb5b1c64c5e9_7c1e4220_cab_f58bd7c0-be73-4a72-a72a-b86bc956f056\memory.hdmp

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_explorer.exe_4a9574a8c4e5da34b0324decbbb5b1c64c5e9_7c1e4220_f58bd7c0-be73-4a72-a72a-b86bc956f056

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 53101454-4557-4108-874f-da5220c1381c
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: e1ecd8026e6b7b6948502bf4cd7434c6
Cab Guid: 0


You tried rebooting in Safe mode -- what happened??

Same thing in safe mode - explorer crashing in a loop.

Did you try classic /sfc?

Hello @Destroy666 - Yes, sfc /scannow completed without any actions.

How did you run that command if File Explorer was crashed? Have you tried to uninstall the application by running Settings the same way you ran command prompt?

I already uninstalled the app using powershell, as mentioned in the post above. It doesn't fix the issue.

Explorer is Crashing, Repair Explorer.
